# Mobile view Menu for Website

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover

I was making a website for e-invitations. Have made everything but stuck at one place.
The menu of desktop view is working fine but when opened on the mobile its not working. I click on the menu button nothing happens. Please find below the screenshot.

HTML

```
<body>

<div id="container" class="container intro-effect-push animsition" style="animation-duration: 1500ms; opacity: 1;">  

<nav id="main_menu" class="menugray">
<div id="menu-button" class="menu-opened">

</div>                                                                   


<ul class="open" style="display: none;">
        <li><a class="fade-page" href="index2.html"><span data-hover="HOME">HOME</span></a></li>
        <li> <a class="fade-page" href="knowus.html"><span data-hover="BRIDE & GROOM">BRIDE & GROOM</span></a>
            </li>
        <li><a href="events.html" class="fade-page"><span data-hover="EVENTS">EVENTS</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="rspv.html" class="fade-page"><span data-hover="RSPV">RSPV</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="photos.html" class="fade-page"><span data-hover="PHOTOS">PHOTOS</span></a></li> 


    </ul>

</nav>
```

CSS

```
    #main_menu li a span::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: -100%;
    color:#e76b71;
    content: attr(data-hover);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

#main_menu:after,
#main_menu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#menu-button {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 1.25em;
  font-size:30px;
  top:8px;
  right:8px;
  display: none;
  cursor:pointer;
}
#menu-button:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.25em;
  left: 0;
  width: 1em;
  height: 0.125em;
  border-top: 0.375em double #333;
  border-bottom: 0.135em solid #333;
}
```

Screenshots

[image: The three lines on top right are for menu on mobile view. Nothing happens after I click]

If I change the code to

```
<ul class="open" style="display: block;">
```

initially it was display:none

After changing the display is:
[image: The menu is opened but does not close]

This question might be asked several time. But request someone to help me. I would be very thankful for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry i found a solution for you..
See flowing code:

```
 <div id="container" class="container intro-effect-push animsition" style="animation-duration: 1500ms; opacity: 1;">

        <nav id="main_menu" class="menugray">
            <label for="open-nav" class="menu-opened" id="menu-button"></label>
            <input id="open-nav" class="menu-opened" type="checkbox">
            <ul class="open" style="display: none;">
                <li><a class="fade-page" href="index2.html"><span data-hover="HOME">HOME</span></a></li>
                <li> <a class="fade-page" href="knowus.html"><span data-hover="BRIDE & GROOM">BRIDE & GROOM</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="events.html" class="fade-page"><span data-hover="EVENTS">EVENTS</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="rspv.html" class="fade-page"><span data-hover="RSPV">RSPV</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="photos.html" class="fade-page"><span data-hover="PHOTOS">PHOTOS</span></a></li>


            </ul>

        </nav>
    </div>
```

And the css is:

```
#main_menu li a span::before {
            position: absolute;
            top: -100%;
            color: #e76b71;
            content: attr(data-hover);
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        }

        #main_menu:after,
        #main_menu > ul:after {
            content: ".";
            display: block;
            clear: both;
            visibility: hidden;
            line-height: 0;
            height: 0;
        }

        #menu-button {
            position: absolute;
            padding-left: 1.25em;
            font-size: 30px;
            top: 8px;
            right: 8px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        #menu-button:before {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            top: 0.25em;
            left: 0;
            width: 1em;
            height: 0.125em;
            border-top: 0.375em double #333;
            border-bottom: 0.135em solid #333;
        }

        #open-nav:checked + .open {
            display: block !important;
        }

        #open-nav {
            display: none;
        }
```

Codepen link for your preview: https://codepen.io/ziruhel/pen/gXOBVK